# Combine Nested Lists With Logic

Tags: c#, list, nested, wrapper

I'm using a game engine that cannot serialize nested lists such as `List<List<int>>`. What I need is a quick solution that will store multiple lists into one list. I am about to write this on my own but am wondering if any solutions already exist.

Are there any wrappers out there that can store 'virtual' nested lists into one big list while providing the functionality you would expect from separate lists?

Comment: If it can't serialize nested lists, that suggests that it is using a non-standard serializer...  so, assuming that is the case, what *can* it serialize?

Comment: It can serialize standard (non-nested) lists.

Comment: Any reason you have to use that serializer, and not a standard one?

Comment: I believe the game engine (Unity3D) has to use its own serializer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten nested lists:

```
List<int> flattened = allLists.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

> Would it be possible to unflatten a flattened list back into nested
>   lists?

You could use a `Tuple<int, int>` to store the number of the original list in `Item1` and the number itself in `Item2`.

```
// create sample data
var allLists = new List<List<int>>() { 
    new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 },
    new List<int>(){ 4,5,6 },
    new List<int>(){ 7,8,9 },
};

List<Tuple<int, int>> flattened = allLists
    .Select((l, i) => new{ List = l, Position = i + 1 })
    .SelectMany(x => x.List.Select(i => Tuple.Create(x.Position, i)))
    .ToList();

// now you have all numbers flattened in one list:
foreach (var t in flattened)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number: " + t.Item2); // prints out the number
}
// unflatten
allLists = flattened.GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
                    .Select(g => g.Select(t => t.Item2).ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to unflatten a flattened list back into nested lists?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

To flatten a list, use something like others have suggested to make a flattened list of Tuples (note, all code below is untested):

```
List<List<int>> myStartingList = new List<List<int>>();
List<Tuple<int, int, int>> myFlatList = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
for (var iOuter = 0; iOuter < myStartingList.Count; iOuter++)
    for (var iInner = 0; iInner < myStartingList[iOuter].Count; iInner++)
        myFlatList.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(iOuter, iInner, myStartingList[iOuter][iInner]);
```

and to unflatten:

```
List<List<int>> myNestedList = new List<List<int>>();
int iOuter=-1;
foreach (var t in myFlattenedList)
{
    if (iOuter != t.Item1)
        myNestedList.Add(new List<Int>());
    iOuter = t.Item1;
    myNestedList[t.Item1][t.Item2] = t.Item3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify if you are after:

1. A serialization library that can represent nested lists (e.g. JSON.NET should be able to).
2. A way to flatten lists

Comment: A way to flatten and unflatten nested lists.