# Union two nested List<object> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an AlbumArtist class (which is my EF Entity):

```
public class AlbumArtist : IEquatable<AlbumArtist>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(AlbumArtist albumArtist)
    {
        return Title.Equals(albumArtist.Title);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Title.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And an Album class (which is my EF Entity too):

```
public class Album : IEquatable<Album>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlbumArtist> AlbumArtists { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Album album)
    {
        return Title.Equals(album.Title);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Title.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So, as you see, I have many-to-many relationship.

I create one list, populate it, than save it with DbContext, then I create and populate the second list. And then I try to merge that two lists (one from DbContext, second from the local variable) and save the result to DbContext as well (insert new entities and update existing).

I have the following data in my two lists:

```
--Infected Mushroom
----Classical Mushroom
----Converting Vegetarians
...



--Infected Mushroom
----The Gathering ‎
----Converting Vegetarians
--Skazi
...
```

And I try to get the following data:

```
--Infected Mushroom
----Classical Mushroom
----The Gathering ‎
----Converting Vegetarians
--Skazi
...
```

Please help me to write some LINQ query to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to override the hashcode and the Equal method just remove them and later asking in the query by using Where, Select etc.

Comment: Stop listening to old school trance and it will all work itself out.

Comment: "stop listening to old school trance"? pftftftft. psi-trance is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

It can be possible with LINQ with the help of `SelectMany` function.

YOu can find the example of `SelectMany` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636560/combine-nested-lists-with-logic)

Comment: Can you help me with writing query... Thanks! By the way, as far as I understand SelectMany in not my choice... I don't need to unwrap my lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ operators [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) and [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx). To demonstrate this I have simplified your problem into two lists of groups of strings:

```
var list1 = new[] {
    Tuple.Create("Infected Mushroom", "Classical Mushroom"),
    Tuple.Create("Infected Mushroom", "Converting Vegetarians"),
    Tuple.Create("Skazi", "Animal")
}
.GroupBy(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
var list2 = new[] {
    Tuple.Create("Infected Mushroom", "The Gathering"),
    Tuple.Create("Skazi", "Animal")
}
.GroupBy(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
```

Each item in each list is an [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) where `Key` is the artist and the elements of the `IGrouping` are the albums.

You can then combine these two lists using `Join`:

```
var combinedList = list1.Join(
  list2,
  g1 => g1.Key,
  g2 => g2.Key,
  (g1, g2) => new { Artist = g1.Key, Albums = g1.Union(g2) }
);
```

Matching `g1.Key` to `g2.Key` ensures that elements are matched on artists. For each artist the albums are then created by `g1.Union(g2)`.

Comment: It's quite simple with the strings, but when I deal with objects I have problems. If an object exists, I mush find it and add sub object (and I have to check if sub object exists either).

Comment: @VjacheslavRavdin: I have tried to answer the question about how to merge the hierarchies using LINQ. How you should handle object identity is not so easy to answer from the information you have provided but from the `IEquatable<T>` interface it appears that your entities are what in DDD is called value objects except that your classes are mutable. My code will work with any immutable value objects and doing that is probably much simpler than caching objects in dictionaries and looking them to modify them.